# Disable Beep Sound in Vb 6

Tags: vb6, keypress, beep

When I press Ctrl+other keys in a TextBox in VB 6.0, the system plays a beep sound.
How can I disable this in VB 6.0?

Comment: The beeps are intentional though, warning the user that the keystroke was ineffective.  Why would you want to disable part of the Windows UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the KeyPress event and change the KeyAscii code to 0 (you can do it conditionally, to only disable some of the "beep cases").
Much like F.Aquino's code, only that `KeyAscii = 13` is for disabling beeps triggered by the Enter-key. Change the condition to match your case.

Answer (score 3):

VB 5.0/6.0
'Copy and Paste this code in your Textbox_KeyPress() event.

```
If KeyAscii = 13 Then  

    KeyAscii = 0   

End If
```

[Source](http://www.vbforfree.com/?p=261)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Private Sub Command1_Click()
    'Beep off
    Dim res
    res = Shell("reg add " + Chr(34) + "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Sound" + Chr(34) + " /t REG_SZ /v Beep /d no /f", vbHide)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Command2_Click()
    'Beep on
    Dim res
    res = Shell("reg add " + Chr(34) + "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Sound" + Chr(34) + " /t REG_SZ /v Beep /d yes /f", vbHide)
    End Sub
```

For code takes effect still must restart explorer/system.